# Can I publish a yellow paper written when I was employed?

Tags: publications, copyright

I am a developer graduate in Artificial Intelligence. I wrote an interesting draft document seeking feedback from fellow developers, and data scientists.

The paper was about stream reasoning and how I imagined a pattern to help anticipate future business changes on stream data. I was a developer part of a big energy producer in France.

Unfortunately this paper did not get any attention whatsoever; I don’t want to lose my work; As the purpose was to seek feedback and discussion. I mentioned that is copyright of that company as any other work. It is still a theoretical study. No production procedure, business process or a technical solution part of any project when I posted it.

I feel very frustrated and consumed that It had no attention. I want to post It publicly with all the benefit of the open community. My resignation has nothing to do with the paper, and as I said, It was not a mission that I had to do. Even if It consumed some time but that time was part of innovation time anybody can enjoy. Many do not produce anything really useful.

Comment: First, you need to check the contract you had with that employer to be sure who really does own the copyright (or, if the contract doesn't specify, check the default position defined by French copyright law).  If you own the copyright (and as long as there's nothing commercially confidential in the paper), then there's no problem.  If your former employer owns the copyright, then you can try to find out who, in your former employer's management structure, has the power to authorise publication of documents, and drop that person an e-mail asking his/her permission to publish.

Comment: What's a yellow paper?

Comment: @DanielHatton Thanks for your guidance I think that's it. I will figure out within these boundaries.

Comment: @OlegLobachev It's a draft document, not a final one, known in Academia or the open -source community to present something technical or not, that is open for discussion. Something like the Bitcoin of Satoshi which is a proposition in his case and not under an academic or business entity.